# IIS 7 error logs

Tags: iis-7

Where are they located?

Using windows 2008 server/ IIS 7

I am getting a 500 error and would like to know if there is any other place other than Event Viewer that can shed some info, such as IIS error logs. Currently all I can find is access logs - in the inetpub folder

Answer (score 4):

If you make the request locally you'll get more detailed error messages.

You can also enable Failed Request Trace logs by going to Start>Run>Server Manager, Roles, Web Server(IIS),  Add Role Services then check Web Server\Health and Diagnostics\Tracing.  You'll need to enable this per-site by right-clicking on your site in inetmgr and then Failed Request Tracing.  By default these logs will appear in  %systemdrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC<ID>

Comment: + c:\windows\system32\logfiles\httperr

Comment: Don't forget to check the Windows Application Event Log too!